# PHP command-line tool to work on Windows

Tags: php, windows, command-line

All the code/commands below are part of a PHP script that processes images from the command line, it is for a Linux system, I need to figure out how to translate these commands to work on a Windows system.

I thought about possibly switching it to use the native PHP filesystem functions but I am not sure because of things like `-rf` and `-f` that are in these commands below.

Could someone please help me, I need the 5 below translated to work in a PHP script on a Windows system instead of Unix/linux

```
line 100
exec("rm -rf {$this->tmp_path}");

line 219
exec("rm -f $raw_file");

line 281
exec("mv $quant_file {$this->tmp_path}/{$src_filename}-quant.png");

line 289
exec("rm -f $quant_file");

line 295
exec("rm -f $out_file");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `rm -rf` → `rd /s /q`
- `rm -f` → `del /f`
- `mv` → `move`

Of course, if you want your script to work on *both* Windows and Unix, then you have some more work to do. But the PHP native functions ([`rmdir`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php), [`unlink`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) and [`rename`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php)) are trivial to use in this case, actually:

```
rmdir($this->tmp_path);
unlink($raw_file);
rename($quant_file, "{$this->tmp_path}/{$src_filename}-quant.png");
unlink($quant_file);
unlink($out_file);
```

(Roughly, it's untested and I haven't touched PHP in half a decade.)

Comment: I was just going over the PHP functions when you posted this, you came up with the same thing I did as far as that except for the rename() one I was thinking copy() and then unlink the original, do you think the rename would be better though for this?  thanks for the help

Comment: I have no idea. It's the direct analogue for `mv` in PHP, though.